# Xcode UI tests - adding tests to test classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, coded-ui-tests, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to add tests to already existing UI test classes in Xcode? I have looked at the quick help and there were ways to add new tests *classes* and *targets* but not tests to pre-existing test classes. Just creating new methods of the class did not help either. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test class extends `XCTestCase` and is in the testing target, any method that starts with `test` and takes no arguments will be executed as a test.